# brodcasting 2D index select in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor of shape `P.shape=[N,k]` and an index tensor of shape `ind.shape=[L,N]`, where `ind[i,j]`  is a column in `P[j]` (`ind[i,j] < k` always).
I wish to create a new tensor of dims `[L,n]`, where the functionality can be generated using a for loop in the following manner:

```
    new= []
    num_points = P.shape[-1]
    for experiment in range(ind.shape[0]):
        new.append(P[torch.arange(num_points),ind[exp]])
    new= torch.stack(new)
```

But as `L` is really big, the code is extremely slow.
Using `repeat` I managed to replicate the functionality

```
new = P.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,L,1,1).reshape(-1,*P.shape[1:])
new = new.gather(2,ind.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze(2)
```

But as `L` is really big I have an OOM exception on the `.repeat(1,L,1,1)` line.
I was wondering if I can accomplish something similar using broadcasting?

Answer (score 0):

For future references
While `repeat` is costly, `expand` was exactly what I needed

```
new = P.unsqueeze(1).expand(-1,L,-1,-1).reshape(-1,*P.shape[1:])
new = new.gather(2,ind.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze(2)
```